# How does ASP.NET MVC globalization work with my own ResourceProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, globalization

i create a new class which inherite the IResourceProvider,and register it in web.config

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="xx.xxx.xxxx" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

this new class just implement

```
public GetObject(string resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
{
   ....
}
```

which will get globalization text from my own db.

question is how i can use it in validation Attribute, such as below syntax:

```
[StringLength(5, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength")]  
public string StringLength { get; set; }
```

and also how use it in view directly?
in classic web form, i can just use

```
<asp:Literal ID="test" runat="server" Text="<%$ resources:Text,123 %>"></asp:Literal>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and also how use it in view directly?

You should be able to reference your resource class in the view with something like this:

```
<%: xx.xxx.xxxx.IdOfString >
```

If you don't want to fully qualify the class/namespace on each view you can declare the xx.xxx.xxxx namespace on your web.config under the pages/namespaces section and then you could use:

```
<%: xxxx.IdOfString %>
```